# Second Volume of Elements of Homotopy Theory?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In the preface of *Elements of Homotopy Theory* (GTM 61) by George W. Whitehead, he wrote that "I plan to devote a second volume to these developments". Does any one know if George eventually published the second volume?

Answer (score 1):

He never did, sadly. This is rather unfortunate, given how beautifully written this gold standard in Homotopy Theory really is!

Comment: It's probably for the best because unlike the classical material of the first volume, the material of the proposed second volume-which I assume would contain advanced  topics like obstruction theory and model categories-would be hopelessly out of date by now. Strom or May/Ponto would serve a student much better now on these topics.